# PlatformIO doesn't know the SoftwareSerial.h lib

Tags: c++, platformio

I'm using the Adafruit_GPS.h lib, the problem ist that it doesn't know thee SoftwareSerial.h. but it's installed. The project is build on VSCode and PlaformIO. How can I fix that?

In file included from .pio/libdeps/nanoatmega328/Adafruit GPS Library/src/Adafruit_GPS 2.cpp:31:0:
.pio/libdeps/nanoatmega328/Adafruit GPS Library/src/Adafruit_GPS.h:61:28: fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory

---

- Looking for SoftwareSerial.h dependency? Check our library registry!
- 
- CLI  > platformio lib search "header:SoftwareSerial.h"
- Web  > https://registry.platformio.org/search?q=header:SoftwareSerial.h
- 

---

compilation terminated.
*** [.pio/build/nanoatmega328/libf12/Adafruit GPS Library/Adafruit_GPS 2.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from .pio/libdeps/nanoatmega328/Adafruit GPS Library/src/Adafruit_GPS.cpp:31:0:
.pio/libdeps/nanoatmega328/Adafruit GPS Library/src/Adafruit_GPS.h:61:28: fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory

---

- Looking for SoftwareSerial.h dependency? Check our library registry!
- 
- CLI  > platformio lib search "header:SoftwareSerial.h"
- Web  > https://registry.platformio.org/search?q=header:SoftwareSerial.h
- 

---

compilation terminated.
*** [.pio/build/nanoatmega328/libf12/Adafruit GPS Library/Adafruit_GPS.cpp.o] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on community.platformio.org (https://community.platformio.org/t/adafruit-gps-library-cannot-compile-because-softwareserial-is-missing/18703/7).

You need to comment an `IF ENDIF` this way:

```
//#if (defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266)) && defined(USE_SW_SERIAL)
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//#endif
```